# It seems moderator rollback bypasses modified revision history

Tags: support, rollbacks, moderator-abilities

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292520/how-to-append-jason-data-into-select-tag-in-ajax-javascript) saying that the OP should be contacted since there were some credentials in the question itself.

My flag was marked as helpful and looking at history, you can see that ALL revisions got the credentials changed.

However, revision #6, a rollback from a moderator, seems to have used the original revision and put back the credentials back in.

(I flagged it again with a link to this post.)

FYI, question is now properly redacted

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This was down to me being an idiot, and was not caused by a bug in the redaction tool.

The link to the "redact" tool is in the same list of links as the "rollback" option. Instead of clicking "redact" for revision 4, I instead clicked "rollback" (and the successive "confirm" dialog).

[image]

This misclick, coupled with the fact that the diff for each revision on a question's revision page is **not** updated after we perform a redaction *until* another moderator approves the redaction (i.e. some time later), meant that chaos ensued as I tried to figure out what additional revisions I then needed to redact in order to undo my misclick.

.... it seems I missed some. Hence the current mess.

---

I've had another shot at redacting more revisions. Odds are currently 5/2 on me having done it correctly this time.

Comment: Don't be too harsh on yourself, we are all humain :-)

Comment: So... I was right but wrong... umm...

Comment: It's just an insiduous rumour that mods are human. Don't spread it.

Comment: dat edit comment link

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier … edit edit summary?

Comment: @Deduplicator They're not human, they're [_"just monkeys who has guns in there hands"_](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5dp.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Moderators can directly edit/redact the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274/213575):

> Choosing this, you'll be provided with the standard editing controls where you can remove the sensitive details. Once you've saved the changes it will go into the moderator queue as a new flag for review by another mod. This is so there will be some sanity checking before the redaction takes place. When the revision takes place, **the original revision is redacted** and a special PostHistory entry is created to store the original version and serve as a record that the redaction took place.

The moderator redacted the revision and then the rollback happened after.

Comment: problem is the rollback didn't use the redacted revision

Comment: @Fredou then cast a flag to make sure all revisions are redacted.

Comment: already did, posting the issue here so it can be "recorded" / "fixed" somehow for the future